# Find if the values in two different lists match or not in python

Tags: python, tkinter

Good evening!
In my project I have two button to choose to go left or right. The correct path is the one stored in the self.path variable. In my def function I'm triying to print if the path is correct or not but I'm having problem with it:
the first if statement doesn't print "correct" when the button left is pressed at the beginning and the second if statement also doesn't work (it should match self.path and self.chance stored values everytime a button is pressed and tell me if the answer is right or not) Can someone help me?

```
        self.path = ["left", "left", "right"]         

        self.chance = []
 
        self.button_left  = tk.Button(self, text="left", command=self.left)
        self.button_right = tk.Button(self, text="right", command=self.right)
        self.button_left.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.button_right.grid(row=0, column=0)

    def left(self):
         self.chance.append("left")   
         self.function()
        

    def right(self):
        self.chance.append("right")
        self.function()
        

    def function(self):
        if len(self.chance) == 0 and self.chance[0] == self.path[0]:         
            print("correct")     
        else:
            print("wrong")      
           
        if len(self.chance) >= 1:
            item_list += 1
            self.chance[item_list] == self.path[item_list]
            print("correct")
        else:
            print("wrong")
```

Comment: Bit issue understanding the code
`if len(self.chance) == 0 and self.chance[0] == self.path[0]:`
...
if the list is empty compare the first element from that list? 
this never happens because it is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first if statement, it is impossible that `self.chance` is an empty list (`len(self.chance) == 0`) AND that `self.chance[0]` exists. Therefore, the first if statement will always print `wrong`.

For the second if statement, there is a line of code in there which says `self.chance[item_list] == self.path[item_list]`, which is simply a comparison which does not do anything by itself. I assume this comparison is the one you want to put in your if statement, instead of `len(self.chance) >= 1`?

Comment: Yes, thank you! It was really simple to solve the first issue (it should have been if len(self.chance) == 1) and I fixed also the second one according to it! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want `function()` to do is verify that `path` matches `chance` up to the length of `chance`.  This is easy to accomplish by slicing `path` equal to the length of `chance` and then simply comparing the result:

```
def function():
    if self.chance == self.path[:len(self.chance)]:
        print("correct")
    else:
        print("wrong")
```